# WooCommerce: Check if is shop page and not archive / category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to check if I'm on the WooCommerce shop page.

There is the conditional tag `is_shop()`. But that's `true` even if I'm on an archive page.

The shop page returns also `true` if I check for `is_archive()` and/or `is_post_type_archive()`.

I tried to check for the page ID of the shop page (in my case 6) with `is_page('6')`.
But `is_page()` always returns `false` on the shop page?!

Is there any way to check if I'm on the shop page and no other page/archive?

I do have some archives like a vendor archive from "WC Vendors Pro" which doesn't have any conditional tags. Therefore I need to know exactly if I'm on the shop page (with ID 6) or not.

Comment: Does the following work? `if ( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) == 6 ) {..`

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm using it like this: `if ( is_shop() && !is_search() && wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) == 6 ) : `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this custom way also,

```
function shop_page_url_condition(){
    global $wp;
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged');

    $shop_page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
    if(empty($shop_page_id)){return;}
    $shop_page_url = get_permalink($shop_page_id );
    
    if (!empty($paged)) {
        $shop_page_url = get_permalink($shop_page_id ).'page/'.$paged.'/';      
    }   
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request.'/'));
    if( $shop_page_url == $current_url) {
        return true;
    }else{      
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed the output to true and false. Works great, thank you!

Comment: if your using it as a function with returning true or false then you should need to remove the add_action('wp','shop_page_url_condition');

Comment: Is there an option to check if the url part of the current page? For example: I'm on the page `example.com/shop/page/4`. On that page it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please try this one
`function shop_page_url_condition(){
 global $wp;
 $paged = get_query_var( 'paged');

 $shop_page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
 if(empty($shop_page_id)){return;}
 $shop_page_url = get_permalink($shop_page_id );
 
 if (!empty($paged)) {
  $shop_page_url = get_permalink($shop_page_id ).'page/'.$paged.'/';  
 } 
 $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request.'/'));
 if( $shop_page_url == $current_url) {
  return true;
 }else{  
  return false;
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
if (is_shop() && !property_exists(get_queried_object(), 'slug'))
```

This will work, since the global object of the store's homepage does not contain the "slug" property.